# conditional format rules not working in google-sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Morning I have the sheet that I am testng to see why the CF rules are not staying on this one sheet.
I'm not good at writing these formulas, (newbie)  but it seems to me that they are pulling info from blank cells.. I have the pics but can't post them here. I tried the google sheet community but no avail users

from one of them it seems to be using blank cells .
O1:O3, P1:P5, R1:S3, T1:T5, W1, X1:X6, Y1:AG4, V2:V4, W3:W4, R5:S5, V6, T8:AG196

To have the cells add or subtract and change the cell color according to the
plus or minus of the cell. (red), (orange) (yellow) (pink)

O1:O3, P1:P5, R1:S3, T1:T5, W1, X1:X6, Y1:AG4, V2:V4, W3:W4, R5:S5, V6, T8:AG196

=AND(A:A=29,O:O>3)  (pink)
.........................................................

O1:O3,P1:P5,R1:S3,T1:T5,W1,X1:X6,Y1:AG4,V2:V4,W3:W4,R5:S5,V6,T8:AG196

=AND(A:A=26,O:O>45)   (yellow)
.........................................................
O1:O3,P1:P5,R1:S3,T1:T5,W1,X1:X6,Y1:AG4,V2:V4,W3:W4,R5:S5,V6,T8:AG196

=AND(A:A=26,O:O>60)   (orange)
..........................................................

O1:O3,P1:P5,R1:S3,T1:T5,W1,X1:X6,Y1:AG4,V2:V4,W3:W4,R5:S5,V6,T8:AG196

=AND(A:A=26,O:O>90)  (red)
...........................................................

screen1
screen2
screen3
screen4
screen5

Comment: Hello! Can't you share a sample spreadsheet? Or if you have the pictures you can copy and paste them in here, or screenshot and paste
And I don't understand if all those cells need to modify according to the total sum of those columns?? Maybe something like this in pink option? =AND(SUM($A:$A)=29,SUM($O:$O)>3)

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as text table (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. Click here to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as it is easier to copy/paste. Your table should be a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I can send to email. Im sure it is something easy for you guys here.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try locking your references:

```
=AND($A:$A=29; $O:$O>3)
```

Comment: just did it for one of them and nothing happened.  :(

Comment: @user20213399 can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PFxbgaBqSfpkZbqV0dtlk7jEPKik0tHFLoM2GJQSd_E/edit#gid=1869906337     maylive tracking this the one not working.  this is one from months ago when it was working according to the user.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ue6wgDJoGZEGcb2z0DTg-zDTnA9R2ah41gC3cxUfe84/edit#gid=1869906337     (maylive tracking

Comment: @user20213399 sheet is private

Comment: email to add to the sheet

Comment: I think the range is off ::O1:O3,P1:P5,R1:S3,T1:T5,W1,X1:X6,Y1:AG4,V2:V4,W3:W4,R5:S5,V6,T8:AG137   I don't see any data in half of these fields?  the custom formula seems correct.  =AND(A:A=26,O:O>90), the color associated with the formula is not changing.

Comment: can this be simplified. I just want each cell in the T row to follow the custom color formula.  ex:  if the number in the cell is greater than 90 change cell color to red.  =AND(A:A=26,O:O>90) and =AND(A:A=26,O:O>60) orange, etc.  the apply range to me is all over the place just to get to the (custom formula is) here is the apply range.  O1:O3,P1:P5,R1:S3,T1:T5,W1,X1:X6,Y1:AG4,V2:V4,W3:W4,R5:S5,V6,T8:AG137